# ffmpeg - Buffer the whole output file before writing to OutputStream

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, transcoding

I'm building a transcoder on AWS Lambda. It reads a video file (of any format) from S3 and it outputs an mp4 file to S3.

When using ffmpeg to stream the output file to S3, it is required to use "-movflags frag_keyframe", and the generated file will be a fragmented mp4.

Is there any way I can write to an OutputStream and get a non-fragmented mp4? Something like buffering the whole output file before writing it to the OutputStream?

Discarded solutions:

- Write the output file on the /tmp storage of the Lambda function and then copy the non-fragmented mp4 to S3. Problem: it has a limited size of 512 MB.
- Create a RAM Disk (3008 MB) on AWS Lambda and write the output file there before copying to S3. Problem: it's not possible to create a RAM Disk on AWS Lambda.